# Sequence of primes by concatenating digits in a given base.

Tags: sequences-and-series, prime-numbers

Given a base, $b$ is there is a sequence $\lbrace a_n\rbrace_{n\geq 0}$ where $a_k \in \lbrace 1,2\cdots, b-1\rbrace$so that the sequence:

$$b_n:= \sum_{k=0}^n a_kb^k$$

is a sequence of primes numbers (or $1$, allowing $a_0$ to be be $1$)?

For $b=2$ the sequence is finite: $1,11,111$ are primes (or $1$) but $1111 = 11·101$

For $b=3$ the longest of such sequences of primes is $2,12,212$ but $1212 = 101·12$ and $2212 = 102·21$

I've noticed that $1,31,331,3331,\cdots,33333331$ in base $10$, are primes thus far but I haven't been able to check if it's true for $333333331$ or $a33333331$ for that matter (also, it doesn't apear in OEIS). But I'm almost certain that eventually that sequence will lead to a composite number.

So is there a base $b$ so that the sequence of primes is infinite?

For the sequence $1,31,331,\cdots$ what's the smallest composite?

Comment: Don't give context first. Ask your question first. The first thing your reader needs to know is, "Can I be of any help to this person?" and reading lots of context first is time-consuming, causing some people who might be able to help you to skip your question.

Comment: $333333331 = 17 \cdot 19607843$

Comment: Removed context.

Comment: @MikkoKorhonen that's great! Any idea for the other question?

Comment: @DarthGeek: At least in base 10, there is no example of such an infinite sequence. See http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TruncatablePrime.html

Comment: Such a base is unlikely to exist. At each step of the way, there are only $b-1$ choices available for the extension, but once the number of "digits" gets big, the primes are so few and far between that it's unlikely that any of the $b-1$ extensions is prime.

Comment: For a regular pattern like ...aaa1, put $u_n=1+a(b+\cdots+b^n)$. This is a recurrent sequence of the form $\alpha+\beta b^n$, and a result of J.Berstel (Acta Arithm, 30, 1976-77, 5-17)  say that if there exists a $k$ such that for all $n$, $u_n$ has at most $k$ prime divisors, then $u_n$ has a special form: there exists $d\geq 1$, $c_r$ and $d_r$ such that for $r=0,\cdots,d-1$ we have $u_{kd+r}=c_r d_r^k$. As $u_n$ does not satisfy this property ($\alpha$ is not $0$), you cannot have $u_n$ prime for all $n$.